# In Unity, how do I create a dynamic background that blends at runtime between two different simple textures?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blend

So I know I'm not the only one and most of the examples I found were too complicated or chocked full of JavaScript syntactical nonsense.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for questions related to Unity game engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I created first a very simple custom Shader. This example was from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Blend_2_Textures:

```
Shader "TextureChange" {
Properties {
    _Blend ("Blend", Range (0, 1) ) = 0.5 
    _MainTex ("Texture 1", 2D) = ""
    _Texture2 ("Texture 2", 2D) = ""
}
SubShader { 
    Pass {
        SetTexture[_MainTex]
        SetTexture[_Texture2] { 
            ConstantColor (0,0,0, [_Blend]) 
            Combine texture Lerp(constant) previous
        }       
    }
} }
```

Then, I simply added a MonoScript to blend back and forth between the two textures:

```cs
enum Direction {
   up,
   down
}

public class BlendObjectTextures : MonoBehaviour {

   public float delay, step;
   public bool blendTextures = true;
   private Direction blendDirection;
   private float blendAmount;
   void Start () {
     StartCoroutine(BlendTextures());
   }
   void Update () {
     //only update display on every frame
     renderer.material.SetFloat("_Blend", blendAmount);
   }
   IEnumerator BlendTextures () {
     while (blendTextures) {
        Debug.Log("Blend Amount - " + blendAmount);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        if (blendAmount <= 0) { //Blend from first into second texture
          blendDirection = Direction.up; //The default
        }
        if (blendAmount >= 1) { //Blend from second into first texture
          blendDirection = Direction.down;
        }
        if (blendDirection == Direction.up) {
          blendAmount += step;  //Increment blend into second texture
        } else {
          blendAmount -= step;  //Decrement blend back into first texture
        }
     }
   }
}
```

In the Unity editor, you can specify a delay (default is zero), a step amount for blending and toggle off the effect altogether. I have tested this in my project using Unity 4.6.2 and it works fine.

Like I said, I hope this is a good springboard for what you're trying to do in your Unity project!

Comment: That's a very strange C# code. Why update parameters every `delay` seconds instead of every frame?

Comment: Why do you control behaviour of a component with public fields instead of public methods?

Comment: Also, this code won't be able to work if you switch `blendTextures` off and then `on` again.

Comment: I wanted to control the transition speed independent of the frame rate. But maybe you could move the actual render.material call into Update(). I think I might just edit this code that way. Let me test it first though.

Comment: Public fields to integrate into the Unity editor. Easier to change at design time. But you can Serialize to get the same effect if you want to use only private members.

Comment: Since the only effect that you achieve here is visual, I don't see any reasons to separate the transition frame rate from usual frame rate apart from optimization, and premature optimization is evil.

Comment: These fields don't seem like something that designer will want to control, at least to me; on other hand, they seem like something other pieces of code will want to modify. Depends on application though.

Comment: Okay, so this was for a mobile device and adjusting the blend every frame (even when it doesn't have to be adjusted) is more than poor optimization,  but poor design. The effect is time-dependent, not frame dependent. I would recommend anyone who wants this effect on a mobile platform to only set the renderer property when the blendAmount has changed.